# Fault in Json object - three.js

Tags: javascript, python, json, three.js

I create a .3ds object in 3DS Max, then export in in `.obj` and then transform it to `.js` with `python convert_obj_three.py -i mesh.obj -o mesh.js`

There is somehting wrong with the `mesh.js` for sure, but I don't know what. I get this error message in chrome's console:

[image]

[image]

Also here is my .js file:

```
    / Converted from: MyBarrel.obj
//  vertices: 1097
//  faces: 1233
//  normals: 952
//  colors: 0
//  uvs: 1283
//  materials: 1
//  edges: 0
//
//  Generated with OBJ -> Three.js converter
//  http://github.com/alteredq/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/convert_obj_three.py


var model = {

    "version" : 2,

    "scale" : 1.000000,

    "materials": [  {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "_fueldefault",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.5843, 0.5843, 0.5843],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.5843, 0.5843, 0.5843],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "illumination" : 2,
    "opticalDensity" : 1.5,
    "specularCoef" : 10.0,
    "transparency" : 0.0
    }],

    "vertices": [16.2 .................]
    "morphTargets": [],

    "morphColors": [],

    "normals": [-0.0001,-1,-.........]
    "colors": [],

    "uvs": [[0.3286,0.22
    "faces": [43,0,1......]

    "edges" : []

};

postMessage( model );
close();
```

Please help!

EDIT! this should be the format of the .js file http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/models/android.js

Comment: Check `xhr.responseText` value, Its not returning in `JSON` object, and `three.js` is trying to `parse` it as `JSON`.

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: If you are using 'Chrome` then use Chrome Development tool using `F12` and put breakpoint to that line.

Comment: I found the fault. the .js file is not similar to other .js files i checked on the internet of other webGL projects that loaded 3D objects. i ve tried to find a way to convert them right to .js but i have not had any luck.

Comment: Is there any new error after your right `.js` file ?

Comment: yes , the same. also , i cehcked other .js files on the internet of project like mine, and the don't have the same structure inside as mine does. but i created mine using the python sceript. help!

Comment: Still I didn't get, you problem is solve or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I see at the top

`/ Converted from: MyBarrel.obj`

I assume it should be

`// Converted from: ...`

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. a copy paste mistake. it is //.